# How to install apps to SD with adb when SD is formatted as internal storage

Tags: applications, adb, external-sd, installation

LOS 14.1, small internal storage, large SD card formatted as "internal".

Now when I `adb install -s whatever.apk` it fails with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ☃No suitable external storage available
```

But when I leave the `-s` away the apps go to the true internal storage, rapidly filling it up.

Even this attempt at a workaround failed:

```
adb push whatever.apk /storage/self/primary/
adb shell pm set-install-location 2 # this works, get-install-location returns external afterwards
adb shell pm install /storage/self/primary/whatever.apk
```

They still don't go to the SD card.

Note that I'm talking about apps which support external storage, i.e. those I can move to the SD card from the settings menu.

Comment: Did you migrated data to adopted SD card? Also how about the apps from store do the go to settings card when you install it. On my phone (I have adopted SD card) even since I have a lot of free space on SD but not on internal storage it refuses to install no matter what app I try. P.s. you do use adoptable storage feature or app like link 2 SD?

Comment: I think I migrated the data, at least there is no option to do so now, but there is an option to migrate to true internal (although that wouldn't fit). I don't use the Play Store,  but apps installed with F-Droid or from "unknown sources" also go to the internal storage and need to be manually moved. I don't use any special app, just Android built-in features.

Comment: If there is option to migrate to internal then data is on adopted SD card which is fine. However since all installed apps go to internal storage it is probably up to android itself why you can't install it on adopted storage.